# Can I use wget to click/execite a url link, specifically a url that includes a cgi command?

Tags: cgi, wget

I need to activate a cgi command on a camera without using a browser, I'm not actually interested in downloading anything, the command just needs to be activated the same as when I just enter it into a browser.

Would wget do the trick or would it not actually execute the command, and try to download something, I've only ever tried to download files with wget.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can do it by using **--spider** option of wget.

*For example:*

```
wget --spider http://example.com
```